# Warning C4309 - what does it mean and can it be ignored in this case?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Using VS2015

```
char a = 0xFF;
char b = 0x80;
```

Both lines give `warning C4309: 'initializing': truncation of constant value`

But when I look at it in the debugger, the variables do indeed contain the correct values.

What does the warning mean in this case? Can I ignore it or is my code bad?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz5z1byt.aspx

> 'conversion' : truncation of constant value
>
> The type conversion causes a constant to exceed the space allocated
>   for it. You may need to use a larger type for the constant.
>
> The following sample generates C4309:
>
> // C4309.cpp // compile with: /W2
>
> ```
> int main()
> {
>    char c = 128;   // C4309
> }
> ```

The compiler assume that you expect 0xFF and 0x80 to be positive numbers. Like in the example, it is written 128 and not negative number with `-` sign.

So the compiler lets you know that char is a signed type of 8 bits which means your value sets the "sign bit" although it was not marked as negative.

If the sign of the variable is not important for you, use `unsigned char` instead. This will also remove this warning.

**EDIT**

In case **you know what you are doing** and you set the MSB bit on purpose, you can either use casting to suppress the warnings:

```
char a = static_cast<char>(0xFF);
char b = static_cast<char>(0x80);
```

Or use `#pragma` to disable this specific warning for these lines:

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4309 )
char a = 0xFF;
char b = 0x80;
#pragma warning( default : 4309 )
```

I personally preffer the first option since it will work for every compiler while the #pragma option is specific for MVSC.

**EDIT2**

Of course you can always write

```
char a = -1; //0xFF
char b = -128; // 0x80
```

But this is less readable in my opinion.

**EDIT 3**

The new versions of MSVC seem to complain about `static_cast` too. To resolve it, there is a need to specify explicitly that the provided constant number is 'unsigned':

```
char a = static_cast<char>(0xFFu);
char b = static_cast<char>(0x80u);
```

More than that, on the latest versions, no need in casting at all. [This](https://godbolt.org/z/gHlDYH) compiles without warnings:

```
char a = 0xFFu;
char b = 0x80u;
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case suppose I do want those types as char in the code. I want char variables with all bits set, and only the top bit set.

Comment: Annoyingly, casting doesn't actually suppress the warning in MSVC; [it just causes _the `static_cast`_ to emit the warning instead of the initialisation](https://godbolt.org/z/QkAZRS).

Comment: @JustinTime I think this is MSVC issue. It shouldn't complain when the value is explicitly cast. Neither GCC, nor Clang and ICC complain about it: https://godbolt.org/z/_ZHV6K

Comment: It is, yeah.  Just wanted to point it out because the question mentions MSVC specifically.

Comment: @JustinTime Right, I found on the net that this issue was introduced in MSVC 2017, probably before that there was no warning on that. Looks like adding literal 'u' to the constant solves the issue (https://gitlab.fp-studio.se/external/googletest/commit/8b085f0d2168e6e54712d295dcf26feac92bb9fc) I will add this to my answer

Comment: Hmm... looks like the warning existed [as far back as VS6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa733841(v=vs.60)), and... weirdly enough, seems to have been intended to trigger even on explicit casting.  I'm honestly surprised by that. o.o

Answer (score 3):

I know it is an old topic, but I wanted to add a precision.
In your case, you can simply put :

```
char a = '\xff';
char b = '\x80';
```

It creates a character literal (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant) from a hexadecimal escape sequence (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape). The compiler will only create a `char` and not an `int` and then you will receive no warnings.

This is valid in all version of C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

In VS20125, a `char` is `signed` by default, so its range is -128 to +127. To suppress the warning, declare `a` and `b` as `unsigned char`, with a range of 0 to 255.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case suppose I do want those types as `char` in the code. I want `char` variables with all bits set, and only the top bit set.